# Scale image in C++ with OpenCV but not using pyrDown() nor pyrUp() functions

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, pointers

Hello I'm trying to scale x2 an image to decrease or increase it, but I am not allowed to call the pyr functions in the code. Here's what I have so far for decreasing the image:

```
cv::Mat Pyramid::calcPyramid(cv::Mat image)
{
    int channels = image.channels();
    int rows = image.rows;
    int cols = image.cols*image.channels();

    cv::Mat calculada(image.rows/2, image.cols/2, CV_8UC3);
    
    uchar* prixelPtr = (uchar*)image.data;

    for(int iRows = 0; iRows < rows; iRows++)
    {
        for(int iCols=0; iCols < cols; iCols++)
        {
            uchar blue = prixelPtr[ 2*iRows*image.cols*channels + 2*iCols*channels + 0];
            uchar green = prixelPtr[ 2*iRows*image.cols*channels + 2*iCols*channels + 1];
            uchar red = prixelPtr[ 2*iRows*image.cols*channels + 2*iCols*channels + 2];

            calculada.at<cv::Vec3b>(iRows, iCols)[0] = blue;
            calculada.at<cv::Vec3b>(iRows, iCols)[1] = green;
            calculada.at<cv::Vec3b>(iRows, iCols)[2] = red;
        }
    }
    return calculada;
}
```

The error I'm getting on the terminal is: Segmentation fault (core dumped). How can I fix the code?
Thanks!

Comment: you are not incrementing iRows and iCols in the for loops

Comment: Still getting the same error though

Comment: What is the purpose of `contador1` and `contador2`, why are you not using the `iRows` and `iCols`? You can just multiply them by 2 wherever you need them to be increments of 2. To the error, segmentation fault or more commonly known as access violation is an error raised when code attempts to access memory that it doesn't have allocated, from looking at your code, the logical reason would be accesses to the C style array `prixelPtr`, but it might be raised elswehere

Comment: From the documentation, rows do not have to be specifically right after each other in memory, you should check `bool cv::Mat::isContinuous()`, if it returns true, the way you're accessing the data should work, if it returns false, you have a high chance of the hardware rising a segfault.You should use the `uchar* cv::Mat::ptr(int i0)` if the array is not continuous. it takes in the row index as it's parameter and returns an uchar pointer to the specific row, you can then access the elements by the columns and channels

Comment: @Expolarity I followed your advice of deleting `contador1` and `contador2`  and doing the increments by multiplying 2, the object is continuous, however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I am confused.  Part of this code suggests that you are upsampling, but part of the code also suggests that you're downsampling.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The code is simple:

*src and dst must be separate images, not the same matrix.*

```
void pyrDown(cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    dst = cv::Mat(src.rows / 2, src.cols / 2, CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows/2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols/2; ++ j)
        {
            // sample 4 points from source image
            cv::Vec3f p11 = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * 2, j * 2);
            cv::Vec3f p12 = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * 2, j * 2+1);
            cv::Vec3f p21 = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * 2+1, j * 2);
            cv::Vec3f p22 = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * 2+1, j * 2+1);
            // find mean (we want to keep as much information as possible)
            cv::Vec3f p_dst = (p11 + p12 + p21 + p22) / 4.0f;
            // put result to destination image
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = p_dst;
        }
    }
}
```

But it would be great to add boundary checking conditions, hope you'll manage it :)